# How can I have remote access to my application?

Tags: email, command

I want to developed a software that sould be running in a given computer but that could receive orders from distance, from another computer through the internet. Notice that what I want is NOT to use some kind of VCN to use the computer remotely, controlling the software as if I were actually using there PC where it's running. What I want is to send some commands and informations through the internet and the software receives it and react accordingly.

I thought about the idea of sending e-mails to a specific e-mail account and the software, being connected to that e-mail address, would read the incoming e-mails and interpret theyr message, but I have doubts about how to do this and I wonder if there isn't any other better way.

So please, could you tell me your suggestions?

Thanks,

Momergil

Comment: Would ssh be of use to you?
e.g.
ssh user@hostname command

Answer (score 0):

There is alot of ways this can be accomplished. In linux/unix enviroments a simple way to execute a command on a remote computer or server is through ssh.

Example:  (with SSH bookmark)
ssh YourRemoteMachineSSHBookmark -t date

This will make a remote machine display it's date.
You can execute any remote command this way.

Comment: Thanks, but for the time being my software runs only on Windows. Besides, I'l like to implement a platform independent mechanism :T